# JQUERY как работают строчки кода

Tags: javascript, jquery

могли бы объяснить/подправить комментарии кода?Комментарии написал сам,но уверен что не так что-то.. Пытаюсь разобраться в лабораторной работе.

```
var parentId = $(this).parent().attr("id"); //родительскому элементу присваивается атрибут id?

var text = $('#' + parentId +' h2').text(); //переменная text получает ссылку на заголовок h2 из статьи при помощи сборки строки?

$('<a>', { href: '#' + parentId, text: text}).appendTo(bookMarks); // а здесь вообще завал,понятно что добавляет что-то в bookMarks,но как это трактовать не пойму..
```

Comment: Первой строкой мы берем ид родительлького блока. Во второй мы берем текст у h2 у которого родительский блок который имеет ид который мы взяли раньше. В третьей строке я так понял мы создаем элемент "a" которому в ссылку указываем ид который мы брали раньше и задаем текст который мы взяли раньше у h2. И это все добавляем в элемент который хранится в переменной bookMarks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Первая запись**

```
var parentId = $(this).parent().attr("id");
```

У элемента `$(this)` (в такой записи и контексте это window, что вернет `undefined`) находим родителя и **получаем** (а не задаем) аттрибут `id` у родителя

**Второй этап**

```
var text = $('#' + parentId +' h2').text();
```

В первом этапе мы получили id родителя, подставляем (конкратенируем) в селектор `#найденное_id  h2`и у найденого заголовка `h2` вложенного в родителя элемента `$(this)` получаем текст

**Третий этап**

```
$('<a>', { href: '#' + parentId, text: text}).appendTo(bookMarks);
```

Вставляем в конце каждого элемента (в виде дочернего последенего элемента) `bookMarks` (он видимо где то задан) тэг `<a>` с аттрибутом `href="#наш_id_найден_на_этапе-1"` и содержанием `text`, найденым на этапе 2 (вид будет вставляемой строки `<a href="#наш_id">text который получили во втором пункте</a>`)

**Визуально как то так:**

```html
<div id="someid"> <!--этот айди мы ищем на первом этапе-->
  <div class="element"> <!-- предположительно у этого элемента мы ищем родителя, так как контекст $(this) не показан, что за элемента и что возвращает -->
  </div>
  <div class="other"></div>
  <h2>Этот заголовок мы ищем на втором этапе и получаем его содержание</h2>
</div>

<div class="mybookmark">
  <!-- в кажды букмарк будет в конце вставлен тег <a> -->
</div>


<div class="mybookmark">
  <!-- и сюда будет в конце вставлен тег <a> -->
</div>

<!--результат такого скрипта: -->
<div class="mybookmark">
  <a href="#someid">Этот заголовок мы ищем на втором этапе и получаем его содержание</a>
</div>
```